# Is there any systematic way to decompose a two-level unitary matrix into single-qubit and CNOT operations?

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I would like to make a quantum circuit from the following matrix.

[image: matrix to be transformed into qubit operations]

How can I decompose this matrix into qubit operations such as `Rotation Y`, `Control-NOT` and so on ?

FYI, I read a book named "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" written by Nielsen & Chuang, in particular Section 4.5.

Answer (score 6):

A universal method to decompose 2-qubit unitaries into primitive gates is sometimes referred to as "Krauss-Cirac decomposition". Here are several sources:

- [Optimal Quantum Circuits for General Two-Qubit Gates](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0308006.pdf) by Vatan and Williams,
- [Optimal Creation of Entanglement Using a Two–Qubit Gate](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0011050.pdf) by Kraus and Cirac.
- “Explorations in Quantum Computing” by Williams, chapter 2.

As a side note, such questions are usually better received at [Quantum Computing StackExchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).